# How do I find the source of the symbolic linked file in the Linux

Tags: symlink

I'm learning how to use linux on immersive labs and I've never coded before. Could someone please help me with this question I've been stuck on for a while now. It's related to file permissions in Linux - specifically symbolic linked files. Also, whats the best way to understand, get used to and learn how to navigate linux. Thanks, M. [image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **/etc/passwd**

Long answer: to find the name of the actual file/folder that a symbolic link points to, check the info after the `->` in the `ls -l` command. The link **passwd** in your example is a *relative* link. The **../..** means that the file/directory is (2) levels above where you're starting from. A link like this is created with the command:

```
ln -s ../../etc/passwd .
```

Now, relative links work great, unless they are moved to a different directory level; try moving **passwd** to **.config** and the link will be broken. If the link had been created like this:

```
ln -s /etc/passwd .
```

then your link would look like this (with `ls`):

```
passwd -> /etc/passwd
```

and it would not matter where the link was moved to.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've solved my problem! I've just started using Linux and I never thought I'd get a reply so quickly.